# Rebuild and host new version of a website without access to where it is currently hosted

Tags: domains, web-hosting

I have a client that wants their website rebuilt. They say the web developer you made the original website left and can no longer be contacted.

All I have to go on is the domain name with no login details at all.

What can I do?

Comment: Who registered the domain and in whose name?    If the web developer was the one that registered the domain name in their own name, it will be much harder.

Comment: You could buy hosting at the same company that he used and asked to be placed on the same server, that way it'll use the same nameservers and work, but at some point that domain is going to expire... As @StephenOstermiller has asked who is it owned by?

Comment: it is owned by my client

Comment: ...is your client in control of the domain?

Comment: they don't know anything, they don't have any details what so ever. All i know is that they are register

Comment: If your client is the legal registrant (ie. the "owner") of the domain then presumably the contact information on the domain matches your client? Or not? The registrar should be able to validate the client using this contact information. Once validated, the registrar should be able to reset passwords etc.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the hosting company and contact their customer support & explain the problem. You can prove that, you are representing the company by calling from their official phone number listed on the website or by official email.

you can find out the hosting company using name server or www.whoishostingthis.com

Answer (score 0):

Since your client owns the domain name, simply build a new website for them.   You can use a crawler to scrape content from the existing website if you want to copy it.

Then log into the domain registrar and point the Nameserver records to the new DNS hosting that you have arranged.